# How do you run doc tests in feature gated implementations?

Tags: testing, documentation, rust

I noticed that if you have a feature gate like `#[feature(cfg = "nightly")]` around a trait implementation, the doctest is skipped by a call to `cargo test`, even on a nightly `rustc`. I tried `cargo test --all-features`, but the results were the same. (Commenting out the gate results in the tests being run, of course.) I didn't see anything in the Rust Reference about this, either.

How do you ensure tests on feature gated implementations run?

For reference, here's my working Rust version.

```
rustc 1.17.0-nightly (c0b7112ba 2017-03-02)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: c0b7112ba246d96f253ba845d91f36c0b7398e42
commit-date: 2017-03-02
```

Comment: `#[feature(cfg = nightly)]` => *expected unsuffixed literal or identifier, found nightly*. Please review how to create a [MCVE] and provide one when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `#[feature(cfg = "nightly")]` => *unused attribute* and *crate-level attribute should be an inner attribute: add an exclamation mark*. **Please review how to create a [MCVE]** and provide one when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shepmaster Do you use automated tools to generate those two MCVE comments? I would have appreciated a minimally personal comment such as "I think you mean "nightly" in quotes, assuming your build process hasn't panicked, since you didn't mention anything like that in your question." Also, MCVEs, even in the link you included, are explicitly not specified as a requirement for a question. We're all humans here and I made a judgment call not to include it, why hit me with that comment *every time* I don't include an MCVE for a question?

Comment: Nope, they are handcrafted for each question, although `[MCVE]` in comments expands on SO because this is such a problem. [The help states](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help [...] must include [...] the shortest code necessary to reproduce it"*; else the question is likely to be **closed as off-topic**. I have no idea how many times I've left such a comment for you because I've left many for lots of people; I leave one when the question needs a MCVE. I don't tend to spend more effort on it than the OP has shown in the question.

Comment: Look at it from the other way: if someone had left an answer saying "doc tests and feature gates works for me", would you have upvoted or accepted it? I'm guessing not. However, that's the equivalent of the [effort shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/155423). What if the answer had obvious logical or syntax errors showing that the answerer didn't even *try* the solution? Asking a good question and getting a good answer is a two-way street.

Comment: @Shepmaster I do appreciate you explaining your view. For my part, I feel it's personally disrespectful given that we have a passing acquaintance through these Q&A, enough for me to expect (and mildly dread) an MCVE comment from you, and (I presumed) enough for you to expect a certain degree of Rust familiarity from me. I'd bring up the differences between these two interpretations of SO as a medium on Meta, but I'm not up for doing the emotional labor in fielding the discussion or dealing with the Meta effect, so let's just leave it at this for the dubious posterity of comments.

Comment: And please don't mistake my terseness for dislike. It's simply that it feels like most of the time any suggestions I make are ignored or immediately acted upon, so there's generally little return-on-investment for anything longer than pointing out an error and suggesting that the OP try to create something appropriate.

Comment: *we have a passing acquaintance through these Q&A* — I only remember a small subset of regular users, most of which hang out in the [Rust chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) (which you are welcome to join). For example, it appears that you've asked two of the last 150 questions, of which I've likely read / edited / answered 98+% of. It's nothing deliberate, [tag:rust] just isn't as tiny as it was a few years back.

Comment: @Mogsdad This question has nothing to do with Python; using [tag:doctest] is inappropriate.

Comment: @Shepmaster Nothing to do with Documentation, either (if one reads the tag guidance). That's what you get when tags are just words, I guess.

Comment: @Mogsdad am I misunderstanding what a "documentation generator" is? Rust has a tool called `rustdoc` which generates documentation from source code comments. That same tool also runs tests. The tag says it's for such tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Features that are not part of the `default` set must always be explicitly opted into. You do that by passing an argument at the command line or by listing them in the `[dependencies]` section if they are dependencies.

**src/lib.rs**

````
/// ```
/// assert!(false);
/// ```
#[cfg(feature = "nightly")]
trait Foo {}
````

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "wuzzy"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]

[features]
nightly = []
```

Running `cargo test --features=nightly` causes the assertion to fire, and `cargo test` ignores the test. This all works on stable Rust.

```
$ cargo test --features=nightly
   Doc-tests wuzzy

running 1 test
test src/lib.rs - Foo (line 1) ... FAILED

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured

$ cargo test
   Doc-tests wuzzy

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Comment: This is possible to add some default features to the tests with [a dirty workaround](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2911#issuecomment-415998960)